# i am using jsp and mongodb for my project using jar files to connect mongodb and java

Tags: java, mongodb, jsp

I am using jsp and mongodb for my project and following libraries to connect java and mongodb
I already tried this libraries its working

```
bson-3.0.2 jar.
mongodb-driver-3.0.2 jar.
mongodb-driver-core-3.0.2 jar.
mongodb-java-driver-3.2.0-javadoc jar.
```

its running but today i add mongodb-java-driver-2.10.1.jar after that I have following error

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method
    org.bson.types.ObjectId.<init>(III)V from class com.mongodb.Bytes
```

plz help to correct the error

Answer (score 2):

Because the mongodb-java-driver that you added is too old? Why do you use the old driver with its newer dependencies?
Because there's some method you need in this older pack?